# How to Show all possible routes on google map for source and destination in android & xamarin android?

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin.android

I am working in xamarin android and am trying to show all possible routes on google map(like google map android) for 2 geo locations, i can showing single route using google direction api, so anyone can help me to solve this issue..

Comment: You can refer to  [Add a polyline to draw a line on the map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/polygon-tutorial#add_a_polyline_to_draw_a_line_on_the_map). And you can draw several lines with the same start point and end point.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting alternative to true. According to the [document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro):

> **alternatives** — If set to **true**, specifies that the Directions service may provide more than one route alternative in the response. Note that providing route alternatives may increase the response time from the server.

Here is the sample code for handling the [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24011371/5995040):

```
protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
  ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
  PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
  MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
  String distance = "";
  String duration = "";

  if(result.size()<1){
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Points", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      return;
  }

  // Traversing through all the routes
  for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
      points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
      lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

      // Fetching i-th route
      List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

      // Fetching all the points in i-th route
      for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
          HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);

         if(j==0){    // Get distance from the list
              distance = (String)point.get("distance");
              continue;
          }else if(j==1){ // Get duration from the list
              duration = (String)point.get("duration");
              continue;
          }

          double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
          double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
          LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

          points.add(position);
      }

      // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
      lineOptions.addAll(points);
      lineOptions.width(4);
      lineOptions.color(Color.CYAN);


  tvDistanceDuration.setText("Distance:"+distance + ", Duration:"+duration);

  // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
  map.addPolyline(lineOptions);
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.